# Razor URL.Content throws error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I'm trying to add a picture to my email using razor. Using this code from my app_data folder

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/app_data/picture.png")" />
```

But Razor keeps throwing this error:

```
    Errors while compiling a Template.
    Please try the following to solve the situation:
    * If the problem is about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to load 
    the missing references manually (in the compiling appdomain!) or
    Specify your references manually by providing your own IReferenceResolver implementation.
    See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for details.
    Currently all references have to be available as files!
  * If you get 'class' does not contain a definition for 'member': 
    try another modelType (for example 'null' to make the model dynamic).
    NOTE: You CANNOT use typeof(dynamic) to make the model dynamic!
    Or try to use static instead of anonymous/dynamic types.
***More details about the error:
 - error: (29, 80) The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context
Temporary files of the compilation can be found in (please delete the folder)***
```

I think I'm somehow missing a reference somewhere, but where do I include it at?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Update: I tried moving the picture to the content folder and changing the code line to

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/picture.png")" />
```

And still no luck. Any new suggestions?

Comment: Why do you keep the image into app_data? The asp.net app_data folder is restrict. You can't access a file inside there from http.

Comment: Currently that's part of a decision that I didn't make. If that's absolutely the wrong idea then I can push back on that, but we need to keep it in the vs solution in source control

Comment: Anyways, it won't work. Try put a file inside app_data, and try localhost/yoursite/app_data/test.txt, you will get an permission error. The file won't be delivered inside this folder. Create a folder like Content.

Comment: The problem isn't with `Url.Content` or this line in particular. The problem is that the entire `UrlHelper` instance (`Url`) is undefined. It's a limitation of RazorEngine.

Comment: See: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/29 (about `Html` missing, but same concept). There's some potential workarounds there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to put a pic in an email and you absolutely need to keep them in the app_data folder (BTW: this IS a bad practice - they should be in the /Content folder), I would suggest making an endpoint in a controller that returns the pictures on request:

```
public ActionMethod Pictures(string? pictureName)
{
    var path = "/App_Data/" + pictureName;
    if(File.exists(path))
    {
        return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
    }
    else
    {
        //deal with invalid request
    }
}
```

This way, you can keep your silly content arrangement and also put the urls into your email as such:

```
/Controller/Pictures/Image1.jpg
```

Comment: Are you saying that if I were to put the image in the content folder and change the url to "~/content/picture.png")"  that the code above would work?

Comment: Yup. No '~' though. Mark as an answer/upvote if this helps.

Comment: New update. I moved the picture to the content folder and I'm still getting this error? Any other recommendations?

Comment: Did you implement the controller action method above? Can you please post the code that is generating the email, and your controller code if you have any?